# Tcolorbox with top and bottom line made of circles

Tags: tcolorbox

I have no idea how to build the following tcolorbox. Any suggestion will be very helpfull.

[image]

Comment: It can be done with a small variation of [an answer to one of your earlier questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443794/194703), which you never bothered to accept.

Comment: Yes, I tried to modify that very useful suggestion for that tcolorbox, but I don't know how to include top and bottom line as in this new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually this is the same as [an earlier answer by Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443794/194703), but of course a few keys different and also using `\newtcolorbox`. It also uses a trick from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52856/194703) to get a nice dotted line. **EDIT**: Added the [changes suggested by Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532872/tcolorbox-with-top-and-bottom-line-made-of-circles/532899?noredirect=1#comment1347526_532899).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{enhanced,title=#2, 
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,colframe=white,
coltitle=white,colback=white,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1pt,xshift=-1pt},
borderline north={0.5mm}{0mm}{orange,dash pattern=on 0.1pt off 4pt,line
width=2pt,line cap=round},
borderline south={0.5mm}{0mm}{orange,dash pattern=on 0.1pt off 4pt,line
width=2pt,line cap=round},
boxed title style = {colback=orange, colframe=red, sharp corners, rounded
corners=northeast, arc=3mm, boxrule=0pt},
#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{EXAMPLE 1}
\vspace{10em}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing to my answer! After re-reading it, I propose an alternative solution without `underlay boxed title` and using just a `boxed title style`: `attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2pt, xshift=-1pt},boxed title style = {colback=orange, colframe=red, sharp corners, rounded corners=northeast, arc=3mm, boxrule=0pt}`.